# Firebase removeObserver is not working in Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I am using **Firebase's Realtime database** in my app. I am fetching data from the database and do some change and after that I am **removing the observer** which is not working fine.

I have some data in **Realtime Database** like this:

[image: firebase data]

I am using firebase's observe(.value) function to get this value and after that I am updating an entry and then I am removing the observer. This is my code:

```
func updatePoints() {
        
        let firebaseId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firebaseId") as? String ?? ""
        
        let reference = self.database.child("Points").child(firebaseId)
        var handler : UInt = 0
        
        handler = reference.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            
            guard let userPoints = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else {
                print("no points data found")
                return
            }
            

            let pointsLeft = userPoints["points_left"] as? Int ?? 0
            
            reference.child("points_left").setValue(pointsLeft - 1)

            reference.removeObserver(withHandle: handler)
        })
    }
```

The problem now is, this observer runs twice. For example, if **"points_left" : 10**, then after this function the points left will have **8** value but it should have **9** instead. It is running twice and I am not understanding why is it doing so as I am using **removeObserver**. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: try adding ```reference.removeObserver(withHandle: handler)``` before  ```reference.child("points_left").setValue(pointsLeft - 1)```

Comment: @udi it is working fine. You can answer below but I want to know one thing that why is it not working when I use it below `reference.child("points_left").setValue(pointsLeft - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to the above unexpected behaviour is the `setValue` function you called to update the points is triggering another `.value` event in the database. Then it triggers the observer again. Therefore, by the time you remove the observer, it has already triggered twice. This leads to decrease of points by 2 instead of 1.

So if u interchange the last two lines, by the time you call the `setValue` function observer is removed. So it will not get triggered for the second time.